# C# : "Uccellino" does not contain a definition for "number"

Tags: c#, oop

given this two classes, a heap of objects, visual studio tells me that the class "Uccellino" has not property "number", how can I solve this? Thanks in advance to who will help me.

Minheap Class:

```cs
public class MinHeap<Uccellino>
    {
        Uccellino[] heap;
        int capacity;
        int occupied;

        //[...]

        public Uccellino  Parent(int index)
        {
            return heap[(index - 1) / 2];

        }

                public void Inserisci( Uccellino u)
        {
            heap[occupied] = u;
            int i = occupied;
            occupied++;

            while (i != 0 && ((Uccellino)Parent(i)).number > ((Uccellino)heap[i]).number) //it gives me error in this line
            {
                Uccellino temp = heap[i];
                heap[i] = Parent(i);
                heap[(i - 1) / 2] = temp;
                i = (i - 1) / 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Uccellino class:

```cs
public class Uccellino
    {
        public int id { get; }
        public int number { get; }

        public Uccellino(int identifier, int num)
        {
            this.id = identifier;
            this.number = num;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public class MinHeap<Uccellino>` declares a generic class with generic type parameter with name `Uccellino`. Either remove it (it seems to not be needed here) or rename it to something like `T`, otherwise it shadows the `Uccellino` class:

```cs
public class MinHeap
{
   // the rest is the same
}
```

Read more:

- [Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)